# Adding a subcategory in sharepoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, categories

I have a form on SharePoint 2016. There are two columns that are connected. First is transaction type e.g. Billing, Coverage, payment. Next column is Request type that has a lot of options in drop down. I want to change this to, if a user selects Billing, they only get Billing options in Request Type drop down.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using cascading dropdown. Have all the Transaction Types in one list and Request Types are in another list. In the Request Types list, lookup the Transaction Types list. Then you can add a jQuery in the form and bind the corresponding request Types in the onchange event of Transaction Type.

Check out the below article.
http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

Comment: Hi Naveen. Please refrain from adding "hope this helps" or similar to your answers. Everyone hopes their material helps, so this information will be assumed. Stack Overflow is designed to be a documentation resource, and is not a chatroom. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Naveen. Please refrain from adding "hope this helps" or similar to your answers. Everyone hopes their material helps! Stack Overflow is trying to be a documentation resource, and is not a chatroom - even though it is often used as one. Thanks!